# Regex for specifying an empty string

Tags: java, regex, string

I use a validator that requires a regex to be specified. In the case of validating against an empty string, I don't know how to generate such a regex. What regex can I use to match the empty string?

Comment: I dont see why you need a regex the check this.

Comment: prabha commented below that a validator required it to be a regex - this should have been part of the question from the start, not a comment!

Comment: Edited the question to mention the regex requirement.

Answer (score 50):

The regex `^$` matches only empty strings (i.e. strings of length 0). Here `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the string anchors, respectively.

If you need to check if a string contains only whitespaces, you can use `^\s*$`. Note that `\s` is the shorthand for the whitespace character class.

Finally, in Java, `matches` attempts to match against the *entire* string, so you can omit the anchors should you choose to.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

#### API references

- [`String.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), [`Pattern.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [`Matcher.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)

---

#### Non-regex solution

You can also use [`String.isEmpty()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) to check if a string has length 0. If you want to see if a string contains only whitespace characters, then you can [`trim()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) it first and *then* check if it's `isEmpty()`.

Comment: thanks for the info.The regex solution worked :). I use a validator and that required a regex to be specified.Anyways thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Java specifically, but `^$` usually works (`^` matches only at the start of the string, `$` only at the end).

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use regexp in Java for checking empty string you can simply use

```
testString.matches("")
```

please see examples:

```
 String testString = "";
 System.out.println(testString.matches(""));
```

or for checking if only white-spaces:

```
String testString = "  ";        
testString.trim().matches("");
```

but anyway using

```
testString.isEmpty();
testString.trim().isEmpty();
```

should be better from performance perspective.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testString = "";

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i =1; i <100000000; i++) {

            // 50% of testStrings are empty.
            if ((int)Math.round( Math.random()) == 0) {
                testString = "";
            } else {
                testString = "abcd";
            }

             if (!testString.isEmpty()){
                testString.matches("");
            }

        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        System.out.println("Total testString.empty() execution time: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");


        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i =1; i <100000000; i++) {
            // 50% of testStrings are empty.
            if ((int)Math.round( Math.random()) == 0) {
                testString = "";
            } else {
                testString = "abcd";
            }

            testString.matches("");


        }

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Total testString.matches execution time: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");

    }
```

Output:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe 
Total testString.empty() execution time: 11023ms
Total testString.matches execution time: 17831ms
```

Comment: That's compiler optimization. To avoid that and actually compare apples & apples, print each result in the loop and measure, isEmpty is *only* a _little_ better.

Comment: @Anand Rockzz good point, I have updated code with more realistic example. probably still not exact apples & apples but I see 50% better performance.

Answer (score 0):

For checking empty string i guess there is no need of regex itself... 
u Can check length of the string directly ..

in many cases empty string and null checked together for extra precision.

like String.length >0 && String != null