# How to match the pattern against the complete string?

Tags: java, regex

How to specify a regex pattern for "either empty string or 'new entry created' is a substring"?

I tried `(new entry created|)` but `Matcher.find()` on the pattern is true on input like:

> "
>
> Invalid level
>
> Valid level range is 0-14.
>
> "

It is **not** an option to do straight-forward programming like

```
String.isEmpty() || String.contains("new entry created")
```

because the same method will have different patterns as input. In other words, I need to use regex for this case.
I want to stick with `Matcher.find()` because there are other error patterns I shall be using - 'invalid', for instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3164471/738746

Comment: Wouldn't `String.contains("new entry created")` also match if `new entry created` was a substring of `String`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker matching a substring is fine

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes, you are correct. I have corrected my question.

Comment: OK, then my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement actually is to match either

- a string that contains `new entry created` or
- an empty string

then you can use

```
^(?:.*new entry created.*)?$
```

or (if your string might contain newlines)

```
(?s)^(?:.*new entry created.*)?$
```

In Java, where you have the `.matches()` method, you can remove the anchors:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:.*new entry created.*)?", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.matches();
```

Comment: when you say, "if your string might contain newlines", I assume you mean input string; yes, the input string contains newlines. But as long as 'new entry created' is on one line, does it still matter?

Comment: @likejiujitsu: I somehow missed your earlier question. Yes, it does matter; without the `(?s)` (or `Pattern.DOTALL`), the dot (`.`) will not match newlines, causing the match to fail.

Comment: When the input string is a "\r\n" cr-lf on Windows, somehow, it does not match with this
`"(?s)^(?:.*new entry created.*)?$"`

Comment: @likejiujitsu: Well, yes, because `\r\n` is not an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to surround the "empty" section with *start* and *end* delimiters in order to limit your searches to exact matches of the input:

```
(new entry created|^$)
```

Comment: @Vulcan matching a substring is fine

Comment: @likejiujitsu Oops, I misunderstood that requirement. Edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is fine (for Java), just use `Matcher.matches()` instead of `Matcher.find()`.

From the [Class Matcher documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

- The **[matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)** method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
- The **[lookingAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt%28%29)** method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
- The **[find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)** method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

So, the problem is, the find method will find your empty string alternative in any string. To find an exact match in Java, use the `matches()` method.

Comment: And a better regex would be `(new entry created)?` (or `(?:new entry created)?`), which makes the "all or nothing" requirement a bit more explicit.

Comment: @stema I prefer using find() because my string may be a substring.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try this pattern...

```
(new entry created)|(^$)
```

I have tested this code

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String pattern = "(new entry created)|(^$)";
    String input = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    boolean found = p.matcher(input).lookingAt();
    System.out.println("'" + pattern + "'"
            + (found ? " matches '" : " doesn't match '") + input + "'");
}
```

Comment: The regex seems to be correct, but you should stick with the `find()` method.  It allows the match to occur anywhere in the string (which is what the OP seems to want), while `lookingAt()` anchors the match to the beginning of the string.  In fact, I recommend that you *never* use `lookingAt()`.  It adds no real value compared to explicit anchors, and it's so rarely used, you'll probably have to look it up every time you revisit your code. :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have just copied from some of my old practise code to test if my regex works. what is this explicit anchor thing by the way? never heard of it.

Comment: I was talking about using anchors in the regex (e.g. `^...$` or `\A...\Z`) as opposed to relying on the method that *applies* the regex to anchor it.  In fact, I advise always using the anchors, whichever method you use.  That way, anyone who tries to understand the regex later will find all the information they need in one place: the regex itself.  And the modifier flags, of course,  but most of those can be moved into the regex in the form of inline modifiers, e.g. `(?m)` or `(?i)`.

Comment: Aah now I get it. Thanks @AlanMoore